Dagster dynamically created GraphDefinition not showing up in UI
I have dagster instance with a job defined, that creates dynamic GraphDefinitions according to configuration and executes them.
This is my repo.py
from dagster import op, job, Config, GraphDefinition, NodeInvocation, DependencyDefinition

@op
def name() -> str:
    print('Steve')
    return 'Steve'


class GreetingConfig(Config):
    greeting: str


@op 
def greet(config: GreetingConfig, name: str) -> str:
    print(f'{config.greetig} {name}')
    return f'{config.greeting} {name}'


@op
def run_pipeline(config: dict)
    graph_job = create_graph_job(config).to_job()
    graph_job.execute_in_process(config['run_config'])


@job
def run():
    run_pipeline()


def create_dependency_graph(config: dict):
    op_defs = []
    for op in config.get('ops', []):
        if op['def'] == name.__name__:
            op_defs.append(name)
        elif op['def'] == greet.__name__:
            op_defs.append(greet)

    return build_graph(config, op_defs)

# Logic taken from https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/ops-jobs-graphs/graphs#using-graphdefinitions
def build_graph(config: dict, op_defs: list) -> GraphDefinition:
    deps = {}
    for op_data in config['ops']
        def_name = op_data['def']
        alias = op_data.get('alias', def_name)
        op_deps_entry = {}
        for input_name, input_data in op_data.get('deps', {}).items():
            op_deps_entry[input_name] = DependencyDefinition(node=input_data['op'], output=input_data.get('output', 'result'))
        deps[NodeInvocation(name=def_name, alias=alias)] = op_deps_entry
    
    return GraphDefinition(config['name'], description=config.get('description'), dependencies=deps) 

I have an external service which executes the run job with the DagsterGraphQLClient like so
client = DagsterGraphQLClient('dagster', port_number=3000)
client.submit_job_execution('run', 
                            run_config={
                                         'ops': {
                                           'run_pipeline': {
                                             'config': {
                                               'name': 'test_pipeline',
                                               'ops': [
                                                 {'def': 'name'}
                                                 {'def': 'greet', 'deps': {'name': {'op': 'name'}}}
                                               ],
                                               'run_config': {
                                                 'ops': {
                                                   'greet': {'config': {'greeting': 'hi'}}
                                                 }
                                               }
                                             }
                                           }
                                         }
                                       }
                           )

When I execute the client code, I can see in dagster's UI that the job has ran, and completed successfully. I can also see that
Steve
Hi Steve

is printed to stdout. The problem is, when I look at the flow of execution, I can only see 1 op that ran, run_pipeline. Is there a way I can make dagster detect that greet and name also ran? I want to be able to differentiate between them and perhaps re-execute them separately.
